# Docker Compose - symlink in deployment

Tags: php, nginx, docker, symlink, docker-compose

I have an application with this structure.

- `/path/releases`
- `/path/releases/01012016`
- `/path/releases/16012016`
- `/path/releases/etc..`

And

- `/path/dev` (symlink to some version)
- `/path/stag`
  (symlink to some version)
- `/path/stable` (symlink to some
  version)

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
nginx:
    ...
    volumes_from:
      - data

php:
    ...
    volumes_from:
      - data

data:
    volumes:
      - /path/stable:/var/www
```

I known that Docker resolves symlinks. I have thought before deploy I just **recreate** data container and it's ok. But it's not.

I have to recreate all containers taking volumes from data container.

Any idea how to make it better, I mean better automatic? Remove symlinks and put last version to `docker-compose`? Mark parent folder as volume and resolve it via relative symlink? Or any other solution.

Which solution is best for you. What's the best practice.

Thank you. Felix

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to make it more automatic, recreating all the containers in one docker-compose.yml can be achieved with `docker-compose up --force-recreate`.

Another solution would be:

```
/path:/var
```

…then `ln -s /path/releases/06012016 /path/www` when you want to change.

I don't  like much this solution as it exposes all your releases inside your containers. I would rather go for the full restart --force-recreate.