# Docker project management of subproject via symlink

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, docker-compose

#### Situation

I have project A and project B, that A depends on B via composer.
B implements functionality of interface in A.

I have unit tests in B that correctly execute.
Now, I want to test this via API - to do that, I lunch project A and test all functionality via HTTP API.

Given project A, have own `docker-compose.yml` shared with others developers and I can't change this configuration.

#### Wider context

I have much more project B like in project A. Additionally, I have more projects A like too, that mostly have similar shared dependency with project A.

#### Problem

To not run tests, update B on bugs, tags and run composer update on A had simple solution - inside vendor, I created symlink to replace of installed project B.

**Problem with docker is that, on mounting volume, docker don't see content of symlink (my library).**

#### I have

- Docker for Mac - edge

#### Links

[Similar problem, but on build image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881904/docker-follow-symlink-outside-context)

[Standard symlink, that didn't help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080224/docker-compose-symlink-in-deployment)

## Ideas

#### Copy project

I think, about copy project B to given project A vendor, but considering wider context, this is not solution in future.

## Question

- is there possibility this setup to work, without copy project?

If not, then:

- how to manage sub projects or symlinks in given architecture to actively develop project all projects?
- do you have some proposition of work around or other setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

My setup, it to mount volume to main container with overwriting configuration. - for that use multimes `-f` in `docker-compose`.

Then via composer, symlink given volume inside container to project A.

```
"repositories": [
    { "type": "path", "url": "PATH INSIDE CONTAINER", "options": {"symlink": true}}
],
```